# Is there a way to set the stack size using C++ stack container?

Tags: c++, stl, stack

I was wondering if there a way to set the stack size while using the C++ STL for the stack container?

Comment: As @Neil said. Can you elaborate about what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: Set the size as in "maximum size" or reserve allocation space (as in `vector::reserve`)?

Comment: Can you please add some more details?

Comment: A stack is a container *adapter*; not a container. You can use whatever container you want so long as it supplies the operations required by the adapter (a sequence-container that supports push_back, pop_back, and back methods). Eg. nothing should prevent you from writing a fixed-size container type, then use that type instead of the default (which is `std::deque<T>`, iirc).

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. To do so you would need to set the maximum size for the underlying container used to implement the `stack` (for example, `deque` or `list`), as `stack` is an adaptor, not a container, and there is no way of doing that.